# How to get an array index from JSON_SEARCH syntax

Tags: php, mysql, json

My JSON in MySQL:

```
{
  "tanggaldibuat": "2020-01-08 05:05:34",
  "kru": [
    {
      "username": "aisyah"
    },
    {
      "username": "yustinaayu"
    },
    {
      "username": "aminuddin"
    },
    {
      "username": "citraaa"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

When I apply this:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data,'one','aisyah') FROM `tbl_jadwal`
```

My result is:

```
$.kru[0].username
```

But, i hope i can get array index of '**kru**', without '**username**'. Like this:

```
$.kru[0]
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

**MySQL >= 5.7**

```js
SELECT
  REPLACE(
    JSON_SEARCH(@`json`, 'one', 'aisyah', NULL, '$.kru[*].username'),
    '.username',
    ''
  ) `kru_index`;
```

**MySQL >= 8.0**

```js
SELECT
  JSON_QUOTE(
    CONCAT('$.kru[', `der`.`kru_index` - 1, ']')
  ) `kru_index`
FROM
  JSON_TABLE(
    @`json`,
    '$.kru[*]' COLUMNS (
      `kru_index` FOR ORDINALITY,
      `username` VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.username'
    )
  ) `der`
WHERE
  `der`.`username` = 'aisyah';
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00688d0f211851619bb08117ab4b07c0).